# Paste number into Dialer

Tags: phone-app

Is it possible to paste a number into the dialer? (or get another dialer that has this feature). I have Android 2.2 (HTC Desire HD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to use [Number Saver](http://www.appbrain.com/app/number-saver/com.arnonse.savenum) which automatically suggests to call a number if the clipboard contains it.

Comment: Sounds spot on. How about a link?

Comment: [link](http://www.appbrain.com/app/number-saver/com.arnonse.savenum) :) Wait, I put it straight to the answer...

Answer (score 2):

Sure can.

Assuming you have already copied the phone number you're looking to dial, just long press on the area of the dialer where the number appears and choose "Paste".

(Tested on a stock Motorola Droid with Android 2.2.1)

Comment: doesn't work: long press shows me the "smart dial" tip

Comment: That's a bummer. Boo on HTC for screwing up some useful functionality.

Comment: Tested the solution and it works for me on Android 2.1

Comment: @jmbouffard: Which device, though?

Comment: Good point, it's a 1st gen Motorola Milestone so mostly a "google experience" device.

Comment: I can confirm it doesn't work with the HTC Dialler. A very very annoying decision HTC made.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to your other question at [Save a number during a phone call](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5956/save-a-number-during-a-phone-call) could also be a shortcut to this problem: Paste the number in a note application that supports phone hyperlinks and click on it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the standard copy paste mechanism. Type any digit, say 0. Long tap on it to select. Now the copy paste options should appear. On my samsung s duos 2, just long tap too works, but i have to choose the exact area where the numbers appear.

Comment: I don't know if I've ever used two fingers to copy or paste. Trying that on my phone did nothing. I've always used a single finger. What phone do you use that it uses double finger touches to select/copy/paste?

Comment: @stephen, you are right, i think the 2 fingers is really just the 1 finger long tap, since it does not work always, and selects one word when it does. I have removed it from the post. I am using samsung s duos 2.