# Save a number during a phone call

Tags: phone-app

How can I save a number during a phone call? The scenario is that I'm calling someone to get the phone number of someone else. If I just type the number in the dialer, it disappears when the call ends.

Opening some kind of notepad application is cumbersome both saving and retrieving: tap home, tap applications, find the application, start a new note, type number, end call, copy number, paste number into the dialer (how to do the last step is another question)

Comment: Can you ask the other party to text you the number?

Comment: ...or, even, text yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that [Number Saver](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.arnonse.savenum) is the closest to a solution. It adds an icon to the notification area when on call and will even automatically switch to speakers when run during a call

Answer (score 4):

I was also looking for something like this, but then found out a solution that works for me.

While on call, click Home button and go to contacts and add new contact. The active call stays in notifications and you can bring it back up anytime.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Samsung Galaxy, and when I am in a call I have the ability to create a memo by pressing the menu key, and selecting the memo option.

Answer (score 1):

[Call writer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.photonapps.callwriter) app can do the trick.You can easily take notes and also save numbers during a call.

Comment: What's the logic in reverting my edit? Do see [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/editing)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a perfect answer but most note applications should support automatic hyperlink creation with phone numbers. In my case I use [ColoreNote](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.socialnmobile.dictapps.notepad.color.note) and the process would be "open app" -> "create new note" -> "write #" -> "hangup" -> "click on number" and the call starts...

Answer (score 0):

On my phone (Nexus S), all outgoing calls are logged in the call log -- from which you can long-press to add the number to your contacts.