# Reminder To Call

Tags: contacts, to-do-list

I often find myhself at the end of the day, or on the week end, thinking:
I need to call X and make a appointment, but I can't now it is outside of office hours.
Then I'll forget about it during the day, or I won't be able to find the phone number easily and I'll put it off.

What I would like is some kind of reminder system that has the ability to 
store a phone number and then I can just press a button to call them.
Often this number won't be in my contacts as I won't expect to deal with them more than once.

Ideally there would be away to do this will Google Now.

Comment: Are you asking for an app that can do this?

Comment: Not nessicarily. I am loomking for a method to achieve this goal. If this is a inbuilt function in one of the "default" app, then I would like instructions on how to do it. If it is not, then yes I am looking for another App

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly that way, but you might wish to take a look at [Business Tasks](http://www.appbrain.com/app/business-tasks/com.appgenix.biztasks):

[image: Business Tasks]
<sup>Business Tasks (click for larger image)</sup>

As the screenshot shows, you can put a contact as task, and then simply hit the phone symbol to place a call (calls up the dialer). Unfortunately, this seems to require the contact being in your contacts list. I've just tried to place a note with a phone number inside; wasn't "clickable". Though that might be worth a ping to the devs, which are quite responsive and might be adding that feature in some way.

Alternatively, you might wish to take a look at [Number Saver](http://www.appbrain.com/app/number-saver/com.arnonse.savenum). According to [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/6078/16575) it *automatically suggests to call a number if the clipboard contains it*. Until the *Business Tasks* devs put it in an update, a combination might do.

Cheap work-around might also be to put a contact shortcut on your homescreen. But again, this would require the person to be in your contacts list.

Finally, there's [Clipboard Dialer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/se.grenangen.clipboarddialer):

> This little tool enables you to extract all phone numbers from what ever text is in your clipboard. It will present a list of all numbers it finds giving you an easy way to call, SMS or create a new contact.

Comment: Update: I just got feedback from the *Business Tasks* devs. The "number linker" is already on their todo list, and should be part of a future update (no timeline yet).

Answer (score 1):

With Google Now just say, "google remind me to call 555-1234 at 2 pm"

Comment: Will it  give me one button to call them?
Cos if so, that would be Ideal